# Failed system logging service on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dbus, logging, aptdaemon

After I tried to make a partition in my disk, and I failed, i had rebooted the computer and I was faced with this problem.

It says:

```
FAILED SYSTEM LOGGING SERVICE, FAILED D-Bus System Message Bus.
```

Please, Could anyone help me solve this?

[image]